# SQL look up records in one table based on value looked up from another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sorry, I tried to search for an answer but I'm having a really hard time translating the examples I've found into my own scenario.

I have a table, `INVENTORY`.  Columns in this table are `ITEMNUM` and `EMI`.

```
ITEMNUM    EMI
 12345    6543
 23456    1234
 34567    6543
 45678    7654
 66666    6543
 55555    6543
```

Another table, ORDERS.  Columns of note are ORDERNUM and ITEMNUM.

I want the user to be able to enter an `ITEMNUM`, then it looks up that `ITEMNUM` in the `INVENTORY` table and finds all corresponding `ITEMNUMs` that have the same `EMI`.  Then it uses those `ITEMNUMs` and finds all `ORDERs` with those same `ITEMNUMs`.

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code. What are you using, Oracle, MySQL, MS SQL Server? Retag your question with correct RDBM's.

Comment: have you tried googling sql join?

Comment: Thanks guys.  Yes, I am trying to learn JOIN but was having a hard time, this should set me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.*
FROM Inventory I
   JOIN Inventory I2 ON I.EMI = I2.EMI
   JOIN Orders O ON I2.ItemNum = O.ItemNum
WHERE I.ItemNum =  12345
```

This searches by ItemNum, and returns any order that matches its EMI (not the ItemNum).

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5125c/1)